# Odd spacing is added with CURL

Tags: php, regex, curl, encoding

I have no idea why this is happening.
When I crawl a HTML page CURL return a expected string.

But then when I crawl a XML page. It return something like the following.

```
      < / l o c >
             < p r i o r i t y >
                     0 . 7 5
             < / p r i o r i t y >
     < / u r l >
     < u r l >
             < l o c >
```

The XML file is not spaced like that, In fact the only "space" there is, is tabs at the beginning of every lines for indentation.

HTML looks like this.

```
                        </span>
            </div>
    </div>
</footer>                       </div>
            </div>
    </body>
```

My Code look like this.

```
    class Crawler{
    static $UserAgent = 'Nic Crawler';

    static function Get($url)
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        // Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => self::$UserAgent
        ));
        // Send the request & save response to $resp
        $resp = curl_exec($curl);
        // Close request to clear up some resources
        curl_close($curl);
        //$resp = utf8_decode($resp);
        return $resp;
    }
}
```

Weird thing also, is If I try to strip any whitespace character `preg_replace("/\s/",'',$XMLResponse);` I get the same output.

What im I missing ?

### EDIT

After comment asking if these char were other entities I made this litle code.

```
for($i = 0; $i<= strlen($XmlResponse); $i++){
echo '"'.$XmlResponse{$i}.'"'.' -> '.'"'.ord($XmlResponse{$i}).'"'."\n";
}
```

`$XmlResponse` is the unchanged/untouched in any way response of the `Crawler::Get()` method

this is what im getting.

```
" " -> "0"
"0" -> "48"
" " -> "0"
"." -> "46"
" " -> "0"
"7" -> "55"
" " -> "0"
"5" -> "53"
" " -> "0"
" -> "13"
" " -> "0"
"
" -> "10"
" " -> "0"
"       " -> "9"
" " -> "0"
```

Comment: Did you assign the new value to the variable? Are these literal whitespaces or some entities?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah no, I do not edit the response in any way, And let me 2 min. Il make check for each char. and will update the question.  But the xml doesn't have any weird char so, I dont see how It could be some other entities

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  So this is what im getting.

Comment: It's an encoding issue. It seems the XML is encoded using UTF-16 (two bytes per character) and you want to process it using the classic single-byte string functions. You need to use the [`mb_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) functions (multi-byte string). The exact encoding (UTF-16 LE or UTF-16 BE) should be declared in the `<?xml` element and, possible, also in the `Content-Type` header of the HTTP response (use [`curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) to get it.

Comment: Also, you probably shouldn't care too much about the content of the received XML as string. Pass it to [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) and the [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) classes should take care of encoding.

Comment: @axiac Thank you! You were right It was multi-bytes.

Answer (score -1):

Your preg_replace is only searching for one space try

```
preg_replace("/\s+/",'',$XMLResponse);
```

Comment: `preg_replace` matches all non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern. `preg_replace("/\s+/",'',$XMLResponse);` yields the same output as `preg_replace("/\s/",'',$XMLResponse);`